# Place div's of different heights in an responsive parent div optimze and resolve double content

Tags: html, css

Can somebody help me with optimizing this code? I'd like to have some control about placement. Masonry doesn't do the job in that way.

What I have done now is to create some sets of columns. For different screen width one of the column sets will be active. Big screens have 3 columns middle screens 2 and small screens one one column. The columns are filled with several divs with the same width but different heights.

In this case the htlml loads double content, which is turned off by css.

Can somebody help me to find a way to avoid double content? Thanks in advance!

At the moment of writing it is in use by [www.pcsupportaanhuis.nl][1]

```css
 #l_wrapper_topic_left {
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 2%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 32%;
    float:left;
    overflow: auto;
    clear: both;
    display: inline;
    }
  
   #l_wrapper_topic_middle {
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 2%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 32%;
    float:left;
    overflow: auto;
    display: inline;
   }
  
   #l_wrapper_topic_right {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 32%;
    float: right;
    overflow: auto;
    display: inline;
  }
  
   #m_wrapper_topic_left {
    display: none;
  }
   
  #m_wrapper_topic_right {
    display: none;
  }
   
   #s_wrapper_topic {
    display: none;
  }
   
   .incolumn {
    margin-bottom: 4%;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-height: 480px) 
    and (max-width: 531px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    #m_wrapper_topic_left {
        margin: 0% 2% 0% 0%;
        padding: 0;
        width: 49%;
        float:left;
        overflow: auto;
        clear: both;
        display: inline;
      }  
  
         #m_wrapper_topic_right {
          margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
        width: 49%;
        float: right;
        overflow: auto;
        display: inline;
       }
  
       #l_wrapper_topic_left {
         display: none;
        }
   
       #l_wrapper_topic_middle {
        display: none;
       }
   
       #l_wrapper_topic_right {
        display: none;
    }
   
      .incolumn {
        margin-bottom: 4%;
      }
   }
```

```html
 <div id="l_wrapper_topic_left">
  
  <div class="cblock incolumn" >
   <?php include('topics/t1.php'); ?> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="cblock incolumn" >
   <?php include('topics/t4.php'); ?> 
  </div>

  </div>

 <div id="l_wrapper_topic_middle">
  <div class="cblock incolumn" >
   <?php include('topics/t2.php'); ?> 
  </div>
  

  </div>


 <div id="l_wrapper_topic_right">
  <div class="cblock incolumn" >
   <?php include('topics/t3.php'); ?> 
  </div>

 </div>

 <div id="m_wrapper_topic_left">
  
  <div class="cblock incolumn" >
   <?php include('topics/t1.php'); ?> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="cblock incolumn" >
   <?php include('topics/t3.php'); ?> 
  </div>
  <div class="cblock incolumn" >
   <?php include('topics/t4.php'); ?> 
  </div>
  
  
 </div>

 <div id="m_wrapper_topic_right">
  <div class="cblock incolumn" >
   <?php include('topics/t2.php'); ?> 
  </div>
  

  
 </div>

 <div id="s_wrapper_topic">
  <div class="cblock incolumn" >
   <?php include('topics/t1.php'); ?> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="cblock incolumn" >
   <?php include('topics/t2.php'); ?> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="cblock incolumn" >
   <?php include('topics/t3.php'); ?> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="cblock incolumn" >
   <?php include('topics/t4.php'); ?> 
  </div>
    
 </div>
```

Comment: From what I understand, your code works and you just want to make it better/faster/more concise/etc. Such questions are generally a better fit for our sister site [Code Review](//codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks. I posted on that site!

Comment: sounds like you might be interested in twitter bootstrap.